# Writing a string of multiple date / time to a single cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an array of a couple (the array is up to 10) date/time that I want to write to a spreadsheet using getRange().setValues().  I'm converting the array to a string and it looks correct in Logger.

[Mon Feb 02 14:01:00 GMT-06:00 2015, Tue Feb 02 01:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016, , , , , , , , ]

When I try to write the string to a single cell in a sheet:

```
target6.setValues(source_range6_values);
```

I get this error:

Incorrect range width, was 10 but should be 1 (line 84, file "Code")

Edited 4/28/2014 adding entire script:

```
/**
 * Copies source range and pastes at first empty row on target sheet
 */
function CopyIt(){
//Establishing source and target sheets
var source_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var target_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AhCv9Xu_eRnSdHpLTkc0d1ZURUtyTU9oRjdFbmpMUFE");

// Get source and target sheets - can be the same or different
var sourcesheet = source_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form Responses");
var targetsheet = target_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Work_Orders");

//Get row of last form submission
var source_last_row = sourcesheet.getLastRow();

// Check for answer to Do you need a Flyer Created? If No, end now. If Yes, continue.
var check = sourcesheet.getRange("T"+(source_last_row)).getValue();  
if (check == 'Yes') {  

//Pulling date(s) from the users form entry (source sheet) into an array
var daterange = sourcesheet.getRange("H"+source_last_row+":Q"+source_last_row);

//Getting the values of the array
var classDate = daterange.getValues();

//changing the array values to a string
classDate.toString();

//Building a new variable with the string to be inserted below in the target sheet
var source_range6_values = classDate;

//source_range6_values.toString();
Logger.log(classDate[0]);

// Get the last row on the target sheet
var last_row = targetsheet.getLastRow();

//Setting the target cell in the Marketing Work Order sheet  
var target6 = targetsheet.getRange("U"+(last_row+1));

// Aadding a new row in the target sheet
targetsheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);

//Inserting the values of source_range6_values into the target sheet.  Unfortunately it does not enter the data into the same field and it's in military time.
target6.setValue(source_range6_values);
Logger.log(source_range6_values);

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To give a correct answer for your question, i guess i need to know how you get the value of source_range6_values. 
One quick guess is you might want to use target6.setValue instead of target6.setValues since you want to write the data into one cell only...

Comment: This sort of worked but when it wrote it to the target sheet it writes it in separate cells.  I think the problem is the commas inserted in the array when I first do the get.Values()?  I edited the question to include the entire script less the parts where I'm pull a single value from the source and inserting it in the target.  Single values all work fine.

Comment: One thing you could try:
    var source_range6_values = classDate.toString();

Please note toString will return a string value, but it will not transfer the variable itself to a string value.

Answer (score 1):

A quick & dirty way would be to replace the commas(with spaces):

```
source = String(source_range6_values).replace("," , " ");
```

I've had fun with GAS and variables.  Casting it as a String should let you use the string functions on it.  If that doesn't work can you share a mock-up of your sheets so I can take a look?

edit:

I had to play around with it a bit, seems google's version of .replace() only replaces the first instance (and doesn't allow .replaceAll() ).

I edited your code starting on line 23:

```
//Getting the values of the array
var classDate = daterange.getValues().toString();    

//Building a new variable with the string to be inserted below in the target sheet
//Google has bugs, .replace() seems to only replace the first instance
//-while {} loop replaces all of them
while (!classDate.equals(classDate.replace("," , " "))) { classDate = classDate.replace("," , " "); };
var source_range6_values = classDate;
```

All the dates are in one cell if you change only those lines (and no errors).

Comment: I tried this and it comes up with an error that says... TypeError: Cannot find function replace in object Mon Feb 02 2015 14:01:00 GMT-0600 (CST),Tue Feb 02 2016

Comment: The edited answer executes without any errors and removes all commas.

Comment: You should know that the javascript replace method needs an additional parameter to replace all the occurrences : classDate.replace(/,/g,' ')     This is not specific to Google Script but simply javascript syntax for regex. see doc here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the help you two have given me trying to answer this question.  @swimmingwood fixed the actual capture of the data into a string, but it left commas and when I inserted it into the target sheet, it wrote it to multiple cells with an error.  It did write to the sheet  but the error had you use a CTRL-E (inside the taget sheet) to complete the insert and wrote them into separate cells.

@MickATX suggested the code to replace the commas in the string with a space, which would be fine, but apparently he discovered a Google scripting problem that would only allow for the first comma to be replaced and ignore the rest.  Great knowledge never-the-less.

I ended up using a formula in an addition cell in the source sheet that looked like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE(REPT(TEXT(H2:Q2,"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm a")&CHAR(10),H2:Q2>0)))
```

This formula wrote all the date/time entries provided by the form entry into one cell of the source sheet and ONLY the number of entries (1-10).  I then wrote that single cell to the target sheet via the script.

Thanks to @swimmingwood and @MickATX for trying to help me, both provided worthy knowledge.

Comment: Javascript replace method needs an additional parameter to replace all the occurrences : classDate.replace(/,/g,' ');      This is not specific to Google Script but simply javascript syntax for regex. see doc here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0):

I've read a couple of strange answers here... 
If you write an 2D array to a sheet it will obviously be written accross multiple cells... commas are definitely not the issue but the nature of the object is.

Simply convert your array into a string using `.toString()` or `.join()` (the latter providing the advantage you can choose the separator to use) and `setValue()` (without S) at the place you want.

the commas you see in the logger are only typographic representation of array elements separators...

And, last point : the `.join()` or `.toString()` methods return new variables, they don't  modify the original value so when you write `classDate.toString();` you are not doing anything ...
you should write it like this :

```
classDateAsAString = classDate.toString();
```

finally your code :

```
function CopyIt(){
//Establishing source and target sheets
var source_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var target_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AhCv9Xu_eRnSdHpLTkc0d1ZURUtyTU9oRjdFbmpMUFE");

// Get source and target sheets - can be the same or different
var sourcesheet = source_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form Responses");
var targetsheet = target_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Work_Orders");

//Get row of last form submission
var source_last_row = sourcesheet.getLastRow();

// Check for answer to Do you need a Flyer Created? If No, end now. If Yes, continue.
var check = sourcesheet.getRange("T"+(source_last_row)).getValue();  
if (check == 'Yes') {  

//Pulling date(s) from the users form entry (source sheet) into an array
var daterange = sourcesheet.getRange("H"+source_last_row+":Q"+source_last_row);

//Getting the values of the array
var classDate = daterange.getValues();


var source_range6_values = classDate.join(' & ');// using & as separator for example


// Get the last row on the target sheet
var last_row = targetsheet.getLastRow();

//Setting the target cell in the Marketing Work Order sheet  
var target6 = targetsheet.getRange("U"+(last_row+1));

// Adding a new row in the target sheet
targetsheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);

//Inserting the values of source_range6_values into the target sheet.  Unfortunately it does not enter the data into the same field and it's in military time.
target6.setValue(source_range6_values);
Logger.log(source_range6_values);

 }
}
```

Now if you want to format the dates in a more civilized way, that should be handled a bit differently... let me know if you still need it / want it.